# Socket.io not re-connecting after connection break (Only when app is in background)

Tags: android, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I have created an android application using socket-io and node server.

Case 1: There is no problem when app is active (After connection break it automatically reconnect).
Case 2: When app is in background it is working fine till there is no connection    break, If there is connection break it is not attempting to reconnect and hence not listening server emitted event.

How can I automatically reconnect after connection break when app is in background ?

Comment: Recently I talked to my friend about Socket.io library, he already used it before. He told me it was a good library but still there were some bugs still unresolved and this was one of them (not able to reconnect). So it seems it's still not fixed unfortunately.